# MySQL port 3306 not accessible remotely. port enabled on Windows server firewall

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2012-r2, mysql-8.0

It looks like weird happening, I've followed and fixed all the possible things but still `MySQL` port 3306 is not accessible remotely.

Here's my setup:

**Machine:** Windows Server 2012 R2

**MySQL Server:** 8.xx

**Settings have been applied:**

1. In `my.ini` `bind-address` did to 0.0.0.0 and and thus after exec command `netstat -an` this is what I get `TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`
2. From Windows Firewall I've enabled port `3306` inbound/outbound both.  and set that to `allow edge traversal` as well
3. From the MySQL server I've created a user with `%` all host and then provided permission to all databases as well. which has been checked

I guess these are the actions I took afterward. But this is not working at all.

When I'm trying to do `telnet server_ip 3306` error: `Connecting To server_ip ...Could not open a connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed` from other machines. The local host is working fine.

I don't see any other workaround that could else cause this issue?

Comment: I suggest you save a backup copy of your current `my.ini` file and remove `bind-address` option. Save then try again.

Comment: Previously I tried without bind-address and it was same no luck so added bind-address and still not working.

Comment: Please you post your full `my.ini` content (minus the private details).

Comment: Here https://pastebin.com/tTCuQD8j

Comment: I have cross checked your `my.ini` with my own local server and it's quite identical except for the `bind-address`. I tried with `telnet server_ip port` from my local pc and a remote pc both working well.

Comment: Did you receive the same error message when you remove `bind-address` and try to connect?

Comment: bind-address 0.0.0.0 shouldn't be an issue.  Perhaps check the firewall one more time?  Port is listening so telnet should not fail unless the firewall is blocking it.

Comment: I've enabled the port from the firewall and also I have shown the telnet log for that port `3306`   I wondering if there are more settings required for that port to access remotely not sure what it should be. I've tried every single possible things that I found.

Comment: Are you sure both of the machine are using the same IP bindings? If you ping the server from a remote pc, will you get a response? If yes, then I think you can try disabling firewall on both server and remote pc then try connecting again. To clarify on my previous test, the firewall was enabled on my pc with MySQL while the remote pc the firewall was disabled. I didn't add port exception in any of the firewalls as well.

Comment: @FanoFN  I don't clearly understand what you saying

First, Why does it matter if my firewall is disabled or enable (in my local dev machine).

All I want is to access the remote database from windows server 2012 R2 Which is already configured the IP address

and Yes I can ping the IP address and it's working

Comment: If you want to make sure it's not the firewall blocking something, you need to test disabling the firewall. If you can connect when you disables the firewall then doesn't that tell you something? Few years ago I've been instructed to add `mysqld` and `mysqld-nt` apart from port(s) in firewall exception so I'm just throwing some ideas here. It's just that nowadays, I don't add those into the firewall exception anymore, only difference is I'm on MariaDB now and not MySQL. I don't think that has to do with anything though.

Comment: But for the sake of testing, I've installed MySQL 8.0 on my local PC and tried connecting from a Windows Server 2016 with - my local PC firewall turned on and no exception added _manually_ from the MySQL 8.0 installation and I can connect to it. I'll take a look at my local pc firewall again and try to remove any exception added during the installation and see if I can come up with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried installing MySQL 8.0 on my local PC:

1. With default setting
2. Firewall turned on
3. No firewall exception added manually

Then I tried to connect from a remote Windows Server 2016 Standard using `telnet local_ip port` through command-prompt and I received this:

```
J
 8.0.27
       ZPhqTaMC v|)64Pthmmysql_native_password
```

Which means the connection has been established. I test it further using SQLYog tool:
[image]
and for sure I can connect to it.

What I did next was I went to my firewall setting here

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Defender Firewall\Allowed applications
```

and removed all related firewall exception that was made during the installation so I've removed the following:

```
mysqld
port3366 <-- this is the port I used
port33060
```

And when I tried to connect remotely, it tells me this:

```
Connecting To local_ip...
Could not open connection to the host, on port 3366: Connect failed
```

This confirms my suspicion that firewall have blocked the connection. Now, OP said that the port have been added to the firewall but still can't connect so my first step after that is adding back `mysqld` into the firewall exception.

1. In the firewall setting click "Allow another app"
2. The "Add and app" dialog opens then click "Browse"
3. Locate `mysqld` from MySQL folder - usually found in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin`
4. Click "Add" then tick both "Public" and "Private" checkbox
   [image]

Once I've done that, I tried connecting and it's successful. Note that I did not re-add the ports that I've removed previously but I still can connect remotely. Also, I didn't add `bind-address` in `my.ini` setting.